# How to send RUST_BACKTRACE=1 while running Rust via Cross

Tags: rust

I am trying to cross compile Rust project using [Cross](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross)

I am getting an error and I want to trace into the process by setting the environment variable `RUST_BACKTRACE=1`

But I don't know how to do so while using [Cross](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross).

**Edit**

I am using the command `cross build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu`

and this my 'cross.toml' contents

```
[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
openssl-sys = "0.9.76"

[build.env]
passthrough = [
    "RUST_BACKTRACE",
    "RUST_LOG",
    "TRAVIS",
]

[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu.env]
passthrough = [
    "RUST_DEBUG",
]
```

I get the following error while trying to compile

```
 thread 'main' panicked at '

  Could not find directory of OpenSSL installation, and this `-sys` crate cannot
  proceed without this knowledge. If OpenSSL is installed and this crate had
  trouble finding it,  you can set the `OPENSSL_DIR` environment variable for the
  compilation process.

  Make sure you also have the development packages of openssl installed.
  For example, `libssl-dev` on Ubuntu or `openssl-devel` on Fedora.

  If you're in a situation where you think the directory *should* be found
  automatically, please open a bug at https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl
  and include information about your system as well as this message.

  $HOST = x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  $TARGET = aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  openssl-sys = 0.9.76

  ', /cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-sys-0.9.76/build/find_normal.rs:191:5
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://github.com/cross-rs/cross#passing-environment-variables-into-the-build-environment

Comment: Report unused key warnings ```warning: unused manifest key: build
warning: unused manifest key: target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu.env
warning: unused manifest key: target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu.openssl-sys```

Comment: Are you sure you put it in **`Cross.toml`**, NOT `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: Moved to `Cross.toml` still no good.

Comment: Are there any warnings or errors when you run? What is the `cargo cross` command you're using? Can you share your whole `Cross.toml`? Are you sure that `aarch64` is your target platform?

Comment: This the command I use `cross build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu` and this my cross.toml file contents '[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
openssl-sys = "0.9.76"

[build.env]
passthrough = [
    "RUST_BACKTRACE",
    "RUST_LOG",
    "TRAVIS",
]

[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu.env]
passthrough = [
    "RUST_DEBUG",
]` I get an error about OpenSSL installation.

Comment: Instead of putting them in a comment, edit them into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `passthrough` in Cross.toml is just *passing* your local environment variables. So in your case, it is working as expected but the reason it is not working as you want it to, is because the `RUST_BACKTRACE` variable is not set.

In Linux/Unix (mac) you can check the value of a environment vairable by for example writing `echo $RUST_BACKTRACE` and to set it temporarily by writing `RUST_BACKTRACE=1`.

So in order to set the variable in cross, you can for example set `RUST_BACKTRACE` when running the command like this:

```
RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cross build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Or you can set the value directly in your `Cross.toml` config like this:

```
[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
openssl-sys = "0.9.76"

[build.env]
passthrough = [
    "RUST_BACKTRACE=1",
    "RUST_LOG",
    "TRAVIS",
]

[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu.env]
passthrough = [
    "RUST_DEBUG",
]
```